# Cannot center div above another Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center:

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin-top:16px;" class="hidden-xs">
  <div>Free Estimates</div>
  <div>Licensed &amp; Insured #C98354</div>
</div>
```

I want it to be centered above the div below it at all times.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-02">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#slider-wrapper">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#portfolio">Ideas</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Unfortunately I can't quite figure out how to make it center above the div properly.

Desired output would kinda look like:
[image]

Full Header Code for Ref:

```
<header class="item header margin-top-0 padding-bottom-70" id="header1">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lg navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-lg-1">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbar-collapse-02" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand brand" href="#">
                <img src="images/new-logo-small.png">
              </a>
              <div class="hidden-xs">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A+ Rating BBB</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div style="padding-top:67px; padding-left:125px; text-align:center; font-size:16px" class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
              <div>
                <div>Some Address</div>
                <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span><span>&nbsp;<a  style="text-decoration:none; color:#333">email@email.com</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="fa fa-phone"></span><span>&nbsp;(727) 876-5309</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <!-- I want this to stay centered above the div below it -->
            <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:16px;" class="hidden-xs">
              <div>Free Estimates</div>
              <div>Licensed &amp; Insured #C98354</div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-02">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                  <a href="#slider-wrapper">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#portfolio">Ideas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use percentage in a margin to center navbar and navbarnav. I hope that this help you.

```
    <div class="makenavbarcenter">
    <div class="hidden-xs headertitle">
        <div>Free Estimates</div>
        <div>Licensed &amp; Insured #C98354</div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarmain">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav makenavbarnavcenter">
                    <li class="headerlinks"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="headerlinks"><a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="headerlinks"><a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="headerlinks"><a href="#">Ideas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="headerlinks"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .makenavbarcenter {
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%;
    }
    .navbarmain {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
    .makenavbarnavcenter {
        margin-right: 20%;
        margin-left: 20%
    }
    .headertitle {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 16px;
    }
    .headerlinks {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container" style="width: 1000px">
<div style="text-align:center; margin-top:16px; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" class="hidden-xs">
  <div>Free Estimates</div>
  <div>Licensed &amp; Insured #C98354</div>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-02">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#slider-wrapper">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#portfolio">Ideas</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to jack up quite a bit still as I resize especially in the 900 - 1200px area.